# Создание тени, не падающей на div

Tags: css

Всем привет! Я новичок и я пытаюсь создать вот такую вот тень для фотографий: [image: Какая тень должна быть]

А получается, к сожалению вот так и самостоятельно решить эту проблему у меня не получается:
[image: Какая тень получается]

Т.е. тень верхней фотографии падает на нижнюю, а этого не должно быть.

К каждой фотографии применяю display:block; position:absolute; и z-index:число;

Comment: Как вариант дублировать под самый низ темные блоки и размывать с помощью blur и opacity, получиться имитация теней.

Comment: d.x.r, благодарить людей конечно хорошо, если тебе помогли, но было бы не плохо, еще и принять какой-нибудь ответ...  Серая галочка с лева от ответа....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Как вариант решения данной проблемы, могу посоветовать следующий код (в данном случае вам необходимо тень делать у контейнера, содержащего элементы):

```css
.container {
  filter: url(drop-shadow.svg#drop-shadow);
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.element__one {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.element__two {
  top: -70px;
  left: 40px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.element__three {
  top: -140px;
  left: 80px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element element__one"></div>
  <div class="element element__two"></div>
  <div class="element element__three"></div>
</div>
```

Подробнее про идею для решения данной проблемы можно почитать в книге [Леа Веру: Секреты CSS](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/137213400/?gclid=CjwKCAiAz-7UBRBAEiwAVrz-9XDCjSEFbhAjoLmRi2QNsAhwqYl3Wlm3vzxDyhWcZDrw0uN41xj0cRoCtkkQAvD_BwE) в главе 16 "Падающие тени неправильной формы".

Если коротко, то в данном решении используются фильтр SVG, и упрощенный аналог на CSS, и если не поддерживается одно свойство, то будет применено другое.

Про фильтры подробнее можно прочитать [тут](http://w3.org/TR/filter-effects) и [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Comment: Очень полезная информация, благодарю!

Answer (score 11):

такой пример:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box,
.shadow{
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px; 
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skew(25deg, 5deg) scale(1,1);  
}

.box-1,
.shadow-1{
  z-index: 1;
  top: 160px;
}

.box-2,
.shadow-2{
  z-index: 2;
  top: 80px;
}

.box-3,
.shadow-3 {
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0px;
}

.shadow {
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: -20px 20px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box box-1">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520116575045-14cd65689b7c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e83313f1ba5f599db178773268b0a4f5&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="box box-2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519918387175-5bca15e4d9e2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=dba21abe88de841aeab0828f8cf1bcb7&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="box box-3">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520116647936-d5e8570bdf8a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=7da72c3ff8ec5ab09f257ec6ca5d702e&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="shadow shadow-1"></div>
  <div class="shadow shadow-2"></div>
  <div class="shadow shadow-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это то что мне нужно!